# Set variable into Activiti from Java class

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, activiti

I'm working with Alfresco and Activiti workflows. One of my workflows needs to connect to an external database and get some usernames. Those usernames will be users assigned to some workflow's task.

At this moment, my "solution" is create a Java class with JDBC to retrieve the needed usernames, and create a service task who calls this Java class, but I don't know how to continue.

I'm looking for a solution, and I do not find anything. Any sugestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java service task class should implement interface `org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate`, which gets a `DelegateExecution` passed to its `execute` method.

On the `DelegateExecution` object, you can call `setVariable` to set a workflow variable.

```
public class MyServiceTask implements JavaDelegate {
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) {
        // Do something to get the data for your variable
        Object value = ...;

        // Set the variable
        execution.setVariable("VARNAME", value);
    }
}
```

See the [Activiti user guide](http://activiti.org/userguide/index.html) and [API documentation](http://activiti.org/javadocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Another option you have is to add a task listener class to the task you are looking to assign to the user pulled from the database. You would assign the Task Listener to the "assign" event which gives to the ability to make dynamic assignments.

The benefits of this approach is you dont need to use a process variable if this assignment logic is only used once within the process.